# CakePHP 3 - Uploading multiple images

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to upload multiple images but for some reason my clientlogo won't get saved to the database, It gets saved on the folder path. How can i fix this?

- image - is the main image.
- subimages - are multiple images.
- clientlogo - Is another image (This is the one that doesn't get saved to the db)

  ```
    public function add()
     {
    $teamproject = $this->Teamproject->newEntity();
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {

      if (!empty($this->request->data['subImages'])) {

          $URL = array();
          $photos = $this->request->data['subImages'];

          if(count($photos) < 9){

              for ($i=0; $i < count($photos); $i++) { 

                  $destinationPath = WWW_ROOT . 'projectssub_img' . DS;
                  $filename = $photos[$i]['name'];
                  $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                  $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg','png', 'JPG');

                  if (!in_array($extension, $arr_ext)) {

                      $this->Flash->error(__('Incorrect Image Format.. Please Try Again'));

                  }else{

                      $uniqueFileName = time().'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'.'.$extension;
                      move_uploaded_file($photos[$i]['tmp_name'], $destinationPath . '/' . $uniqueFileName);
                      $filePath = '/projectssub_img/' . $uniqueFileName; 
                      array_push($URL, $filePath);
                  }
              }

          }else{

              for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++){

                  $destinationPath = WWW_ROOT . 'projectssub_img' . DS;
                  $filename = $photos[$i]['name'];
                  $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                  $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg','png', 'JPG');

                  if (!in_array($extension, $arr_ext)) {

                      $this->Flash->error(__('Incorrect Image Format.. Please Try Again'));

                  }else{

                      $uniqueFileName = time().'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'.'.$extension;
                      move_uploaded_file($photos[$i]['tmp_name'], $destinationPath . '/' . $uniqueFileName);
                      $filePath = '/projectssub_img/' . $uniqueFileName; 
                      array_push($URL, $filePath);
                  }
              }
          }
          $realImageName = implode(",", $URL);                

      }


      if (!empty($this->request->data['image'])) {
          $file = $this->request->data['image'];
          $destinationPath = WWW_ROOT . 'projects_img' . DS;
          $filename = $this->request->data['image']['name'];
          $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg','png', 'JPG');

          if (!in_array($extension, $arr_ext)) {

              $this->Flash->error(__('Incorrect Image Format.. Please Try Again'));

          }else{

              $uniqueFileName = time().'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'.'.$extension;
              move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationPath . '/' . $uniqueFileName);
              $filePath = '/projects_img/' . $uniqueFileName; 

          }
      }

      if (!empty($this->request->data['clientlogo'])) {
          $file = $this->request->data['clientlogo'];
          $destinationPath = WWW_ROOT . 'client_img' . DS;
          $filename = $this->request->data['clientlogo']['name'];
          $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg','png', 'JPG');

          if (!in_array($extension, $arr_ext)) {

              $this->Flash->error(__('Incorrect Image Format.. Please Try Again'));

          }else{

              $uniqueFileName = time().'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'_'.mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).'.'.$extension;
              move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationPath . '/' . $uniqueFileName);
              $filePath = '/client_img/' . $uniqueFileName; 

          }
      }


      $teamproject = $this->Teamproject->patchEntity($teamproject, $this->request->data);
      $teamproject->image = $filePath;
      $teamproject->clientlogo = $filePath;
      $teamproject->subImages = $realImageName;
      if ($this->Teamproject->save($teamproject)) {
          $this->Flash->success(__('The teamproject has been saved.'));

          return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
      } else {
          $this->Flash->error(__('The project could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
      }

  }
  $cattypes = $this->Teamproject->Cattypes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
  $this->set(compact('teamproject', 'cattypes'));
  $this->set('_serialize', ['teamproject']);
  ```

  }

Comment: Is the image stored in the filesystem? Try to `debug()` the contents of `$this->request->data` before saving and see if something is wrong.

Comment: BTW: You should get your code DRY. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: I would recommend using a plugin - I use Burzum file_storage and from there do your loops or use Cake's Collection

Comment: @artSir I connected two tables and generated two separate modals. And I will look in to that plug in. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Mary Yea i'm really new to cake/php so learning while i'm doing small project's, I will surely do that! Thanks